# glGenTextures segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, segmentation-fault, video-card

So here is the problem:
When I call *glGenTextures* I get a segmentation fault.

I'm on linux, and here is the code I'm currently using to investigate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    return texture;
}
```

Seems simple enough, right?
Well, I traced the segfault with GDB (the GNU debugging tool) and it occurs when I call *glGenTextures()*, in the file */usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1*.

That's my video driver's openGL code...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code as shown hasn't done anything to set up a valid [OpenGL context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Context), so it can't use OpenGL.

How to do this varies by platform. If you don't want to dig down in your target platform's way of doing this, you can use something like [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/index.html) to do it fairly portably, but of course that adds a dependency.

Comment: On a side note: glGenTextures should not crash if there's no valid OpenGL context made current. It should just default to a No-Op and leave the contents of the texture names array unchanges. That it crashes in this condition is actually a Mesa bug.

Answer (score 1):

As user "unwind" say, you need to init your OpenGL context. You can do it without 3Dparty libs, though - check up this NeHe example: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/

Hope this helps.